# ListView contextual action bar for pre honeycomb devices with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, contextmenu, contextual-action-bar

To use contextual action bar on Android Honeycomb and later, I would normally check for the `SDK_INT` being 11 or later, and then proceed with `mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);`

Now, with ActionBarSherlock I am trying to port this to older devices. Now I use `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` instead of `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`, and inside the `OnItemLongClickListener`, I manage to call `getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(myActionModeCallback);`

The thing is that, when first I long press an item in the ListView, the contextual action bar correctly shows up.

But when I click on another ListView item, the item gets selected, and right after that its click listener gets fired.
(I use that listener, so that when the user clicks on an item, it opens up a new activity where the user can edit the item, so in this case the item gets selected and immediately this new activity gets started, and ruins my contextual action bar)

It shouldn't be happening but I suppose I'm doing something wrong.
I've thought about setting the `OnListItemClick` listener to null until I call `ActionMode.finish()` where I could revert it back to the previous listener, but I believe there must be a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense undeleted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand your question, here's a solution for you.

You can first check if there are selected items like

```
boolean hasCheckedItems = yourListAdapter.getSelectedCount() > 0;
```

Then you can check for the following conditions

```
if (hasCheckedItems && ActionModeObject == null)
//there are some selected items, start the ActionMode 

else if (!hasCheckedItems && ActionModeObject != null)
// there no selected items, finish the ActionMode
ActionModeObject.finish();

if (ActionModeObject != null)
//Action Button Clicked
```

Comment: Ah, right, I was expecting it to happen automatically (as I'm still learning, using a book which didn't explain the matter), I'll give it a try and get back :)

Comment: getSelectedCount for some reason wasn't available as a method on my ListView object. However, this helped me somehow, and I managed to do it. Thanks :)